# Matlab: Constructing a struct from lists

Tags: matlab

For example, I have:

```
A = ['apple','banana','strawberry','orange']
B = ['2','1','1','4']
```

I want:

```
struct_foo = 
     apple: 2
    banana: 1
strawberry: 1
    orange: 4
```

In other words, I want a struct whose fields are elements in A and the value of those fields are elements in B.

I can do this easily with a for loop..., but is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `cell2struct`. Note the curly brackets when defining A and B. Also, you may want to remove the quotation marks around the numbers in B if the values should be numeric.

```
A = {'apple','banana','strawberry','orange'}
B = {'2','1','1','4'}
out = cell2struct(B',A)

out = 

         apple: '2'
        banana: '1'
    strawberry: '1'
        orange: '4'
```